# how to solve c# object must implement iconvertible error?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i want to filtering the record sql database base by time in c# with text box but but i got "the object must implement iconvertible",i don't know why
is there anyone to help me to solve this error?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = txtstartingdate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = txtendingdate;
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        gdvRfids.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Always post the exact error message including information on which line it occurs on.

Comment: the error appear in the line  .........  using(sqldatareader dr=cmd.executereader())

Comment: Most likely it is due to you saying "this is a DateTime" and then giving it a value of string, not a DateTime. You have to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting `txtstartingdate` and `txtendingdate` to a [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) value;

**OR**

If you are happy with the SQL server converting the text to a date time, then
just do

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", txtstartingdate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2",  txtendingdate);
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    gdvRfids.DataSource = dt;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think I see the problem.  I was assuming `txtstartingdate` is a `string`.  I bet its `TextBox` or some other control.  If a `TextBox` just the `.Text` property.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", txtstartingdate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2",  txtendingdate.Text);
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    gdvRfids.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: This is bad practice for two reasons: you shouldn't be happy letting the server do the conversion and `AddWithValue` shouldn't be used since there are better ways. Like the one the OP was using at the moment.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, first point I agree with but I was just making life easier for OP.  Second point is debatable.

Comment: thanks richard but how can i converted the txtstartingdate and endingdate to datetime?

Comment: There is always debate about everything, but if you know the type beforehand, why not say it rather than trust some internal mechanism? Like in this case the error came immediately rather than at a later time wondering why things go wrong when another server is configured differently than the test server and 1-2-2015 is parsed as second of January, for example.

Comment: i use this method but i have the same error to.......i don't kwon how can i convert txtstartingdate and endingdate to timedate.

Comment: @RichardSchneider  can u more explain about the how can i convert the txtstartingdate to datetime???      thanks

Comment: see my update to the answer.  What is the type of `txtstartingdate`?

Comment: txtstartingdate is a textbox and have no type

Comment: @RichardSchneider thnaks.........but i want to filter my record by txtstartingdate and endingdate....so i want to use these textbox as datetime.....so i haveto use these textbox like datemask and i want to use datetime